# Will this be reliable crossbrowser to test and reassign getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia 
  || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
  || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
  || navigator.msGetUserMedia 
  || false;
```

I am thinking doing this on the global level will be an elegant way to both reassign that method name and make it return false in the case that it isn't supported. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats more or less how the [modernizr detect](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/06d79fb179e95f35d509afbe7e209403e3791be9/feature-detects/webrtc/getusermedia.js) works.

Only thing is you don't need to fallback to false, since it will be undefined (a falsey value) by default.